# Elastic Search Sort - return sort-fields in response

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, lucene

I need to have the sort configuration to be part of the response, so lets assume i have this query

```
{ sort: [ {"name":"asc"},{"age:"descr"}]}
```

I would need to have this as part of the response to synchronise my facets / ui state with that sorting. I see there is a "sort" response field, but it basically lists the values which have been picked for the sort, but not which field and which sort type.

Reading the docs i am not sure it should be the case https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_values

Not able to find anything about this in the web, a lot of how to sort examples, also on stack, but nothing about how to reflect the sort in the response.

If it matters, i am currently using Elasticsearch 2.4

Comment: In regard that we are dealing with a facetted search, i am of course trying to parse the "state" of the search from the server, not keep it on the client. Esp. when you deal with race-conditions, e.g. sending several requests in a short time (toggling sort), only the latest is reflected in the UI, you are not sure in which order the responses will return - so your UI might not match the actual response. Beside that, i was not asking for "conceptual guidance", so your answer is just starting a different discussion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in fact not possible out of the box.

I solved this using my middleware. So when a client wants to search on ES, it happens this way

```
client -> middleware -> ES
```

To include sorting in the response, the middleware does something like this

```
result = es.search(query)
result['sort'] = query['sort'] if query.key?('sort')
return result
```

So i copy the sort field from the request into the response and this is in fact very useful for the client, when dealing with aggregations / facetted searches